# If href equals id of another div do function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hidden div with the details of a thumbnail that is visible on the page. When you click on the thumbnail, it should fadein or slideup the div with details.

I have set with jquery incremented ID's to each ".portfolio-item-details" to identify each one and then have set with jquery the same ID's to the href of the thumbnail.

```
<section id="portfolio1" class="portfolio-item-details hidden">content</section>
<a class="open-portfolio-item-details" href="#portfolio1" title="">
  <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
<section id="portfolio2" class="portfolio-item-details hidden">content</section>
<a class="open-portfolio-item-details" href="#portfolio2" title="">
  <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
```

Since this is done dynamically, how can I with jquery fadeIn or slideUp the ".portfolio-item-details" if the href is equal to the ID. Basically thumbnail with "#portfolio1" should slide up the div with "#portfolio1" on click.

This is my jquery code which to add the IDs and HREF is working perfectly but not working to slideUp or fadeIn the div with the same ID.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
 var i=0;
 $(".portfolio-item-details").each(function(){
      i++;
      var newID="portfolio"+i;
      $(this).attr("id",newID);
      $(this).val(i);
 });
 var i=0;
 $(".open-portfolio-item-details").each(function(){
      i++;
      var newReadMoreHREF="#portfolio"+i;
      $(this).attr("href",newReadMoreHREF);
      $(this).val(i);
      if ($(".portfolio-item-details").attr("id") == "newReadMoreHREF") {
        $(this).fadeIn();
      }
 });
});
```

## SOLUTION

Thanks to Austin's code, I was able to modify it to work with mine.
Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdoimeadios23/xpsrLyLz/

Comment: I don't find the `open-modal` in your code at all. That is the confusing thing for me.

Comment: Did you mean to put `"newReadMoreHREF"` in quotes? It's a variable. Also, you probably DON'T want the `#` in that variable because that's the `id` selector, not part of the actual `id`.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Sorry about that, I modified the code here to make it easy for you guys to understand but forgot to replace .open-modal with .open-portfolio-item-details. I just edited.

Comment: @user3256132 confused. From what I read you want to click the image, then for details to appear, correct?

Comment: @Austin Correct. When you click on the image that is wrapped in an anchor that has a href = to the div's ID with details.

Comment: @user3256132 do you necessarily need it to be `href`s? I can do it quick cleaner without?

Comment: @Austin well there are many ways to accomplish this. If theres an easier way that will give me the same function please post. Thanks!

Comment: What austin is saying is the usage of `class` of `id`. Instead of HREF.

Comment: @user3256132 let me know if what I posted is similar to what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="image" value="1">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="portfolio1" class="details">details</div>

<div class="image"  value="2">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="portfolio2" class="details">more details</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.details').fadeOut(1);

    $(".image").click(function () {
        var num = $(this).attr("value");
        $("#portfolio"+num).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/mympvxkx/)**

You don't even need to bother with ID's so long as the next `div` below each image is it's details.

Comment: That works fine but since my markup is different it won't work. I am using wordpress to create a loop with custom fields and all the #portfolio divs are placed right under the body hidden and the thumbnails are present somewhere else the markup. What do you suggest?

Comment: okay so long story short you need something else other than `.next` to find them?

Comment: Yup, think of it this way. If the href is linked to the ID then fadeIn the ID. Hopefully you can understand this.

Comment: Thanks Austin, with your code it gave me an idea on how to make it work with my markup. Check here for what I did that is 100% working: http://jsfiddle.net/jdoimeadios23/xpsrLyLz/

Comment: @jdoimeadios23 Nice job, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this block

```
if ($(".portfolio-item-details").attr("id") == "newReadMoreHREF") {
    $(this).fadeIn();
}
```

Because you're having two errors, the first one is that `newReadMoreHREF` is a variable, not a string in your HTML or a value to any variable and so on.

Second thing is, that in the variable declaration you're using `"#portfolio"+i;`, which would be good if you were about to select an element. But using it in the jQuery iif statement with `.attr('id')` will again cause a havoc.

The thing that you need is something like this

```
$(".open-portfolio-item-details").each(function(){
  i++;
  var newReadMoreHREF="portfolio"+i; // removed #
  $(this).attr("href",newReadMoreHREF);
  $(this).val(i);
  if ($(".portfolio-item-details a").attr("id") == newReadMoreHREF) {
    // you need to access the hyperlink in the element, not
    // the element itself. this portfolio1 ID is of a hyperlink
    // again here, this is referencing the main iterator. 
    $(this).fadeIn();
    // are you sure you want to fade the .open-portfolio-item-details?
  }
});
```

Removed the hash sign and then called the variable value to check against. It would execute to be true if the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML:
content

```
<section id="portfolio2" class="portfolio-item-details hidden">content</section>
<a class="open-portfolio-item-details" href="#portfolio2" title="">
  <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
</a>

<div id="portfolio1" class="portfolio" hidden>Portfolio 1</div>
<div id="portfolio2" class="portfolio" hidden>Portfolio 2</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('a.open-portfolio-item-details').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.portfolio').hide();
    $('.portfolio' + id).fadeIn();
});
```

Couldn't get the fiddle link for some reason.

Edit:
I don't know the name of the class that shows the content you want displayed, so as an example I'm using portfolio. Try putting this code into a fiddle